# How to remove strings with numbers and special characters using javascript regular expressions?

Tags: javascript

```
var string = "[Account0].&[1]+[Account1].&[2]+[Account2].&[3]+[Account3].&[4]";
var numbers = string.match(/(\d+)/gi);
alert(numbers.join(','));
```

here outpout is  : 0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4

Here I need to elimanate all the strings with numbers and special characters.

can you please help me,is there any solution for the output : 1,2,3,4

Thanks,

Rajasekhar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and easy solution would maybe be

```
var numbers = string.match(/\[\d+\]/gi); // numbers = ['[1]', '[2]', '[3]', '[4]'];
alert(numbers.join(',').replace(/[\[\]]/g, ''));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response, it is more helping to me